# Learning classification on an imbalanced dataset alongside regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, unbalanced-classes

I have a dataset of images $X$ and numerical values $Y$, corresponding to them. Each numerical value comes with a reliability $r$ flag (either 0 or 1). The dataset is imbalanced: for each unreliable value there are over 30 reliable ones.

I want to train a model, that would be able to predict the values $y$ and return the reliability $r$ (or confidence) of the answer. Naturally, I want to make as many reliable predictions $y$ as possible.

However, since the dataset is so imbalanced, the model does not predict reliability $r$ of the answers $y$ well. I considered adding synthetic unreliable values to the dataset, but then I realized that this would lower the model's performance when it comes to predicting the values $y$. I also tried penalizing the model for predicting the answer as "reliable", but I do not think it affects the result performance much.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is your $Y$ variable, the reliability itself?

Comment: Thank you, @Dave! $Y$ is a set of numerical values $y$ (in my case, $y$ is size) that I want to predict. I also want to return reliability $r$ for each of my prediction $y$

Comment: @lizamoskovskaya why do you think the imbalance is the reason for the poor predictive performance?  It may be that it is just an inherently difficult learning task.  The first step is to work out the appropriate performance metric for the predictive performance subtask.  If it is accuracy, then balancing is unlikely to help.

Comment: Also, for the regression part, you may want to downweight the contribution of the error on the unreliable patterns in the cost function (if you are not already doing so).